# Why angular app doesn't recognise angular-material styles?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material styles are not working . The components are displayed as below:

[image: The way the elements get displayed]

[image: The angular material code]

[image: The styles in angular.json file]

I have tried reinstalling angular material but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import MatButtonModule into your app.module.ts

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have already imported all neccesary componets.

Comment: Did you import it to the 'imports:[MatButtonModule]' section as well?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion :** Remove the first entry in styles[] array and include this directly on top in styles.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```